# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS user accounts log-in - How?

Tags: accounts

I installed Ubuntu on a Lenovo Ideapad B590, i3-2328M @ 2.20, 6GB RAM, Samsung EVO 250GB SSD and replaced Windows with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (64-bit).

My questions are:

1. How do I go about creating a log-in screen where another user can choose its account from the initial 'lock screen', rather than having to log in to my account to select it from the 'system menu'.
2. How do I change the mouse for a left-handed person?

Comment: When you are on the lock screen you should see the two users and be able to select wich one you want to use.  Could you share how your login screen looks like

Comment: This would really be better as two separate questions IMHO. For the first part, it sounds like you set it up to auto-login to your own account?

Comment: I consider this 'solved' ... very satisfactorily...  Question was answered within 1 hour of my posting the question.  Thanks to all who helped me to understand how to do it, and how to 'reverse' what I'd mistakenly done.

Answer (score 4):

Go to the Settings screen by pressing the gear icon in the top right of your screen:

[image: gear icon]

then click <kbd>System Settings</kbd>:

[image]

1. <kbd>User Accounts</kbd>: This is were you can create a new user account. Once there, you will need to "Unlock" the user account screen to get administrator rights. Then you can add, edit and delete accounts. You will also be able to change the "auto-login" feature there.
2. <kbd>Mouse & Touchpad</kbd>: There you will be able to customize the mouse settings for the current logged in user (to change another users settings, simply log into their account and make the changes there).

Comment: Excellent... Thanks for the 'pointers' G...  I absolutely knew this was as easy as you helpfully pointed out...  And yes, I unwittingly set up my account to 'auto-login' in my 'haste' to get this test functional...  Yep... gotta 'get over myself' in my presumption that what I THOUGHT I 'knew' is ever-so-slightly 'different' under Linux..  But I am one impressed puppy, I gotta say.   And as 'luck' would have it, I just now also 'introduced' her best friend to Ubuntu, as well, and now SHE wants to 'dual-boot' Windows 10 and Ubuntu on her new laptop...  Oh brother...  What have I done..?

Comment: please vote the answer as solved